# Find the approximate disk spaced used by a specific class in an assembly

Tags: .net, assemblies, reflector

Is it possible to determine the disk spaced used by a class, namespace or method in an assembly? For example in Reflector you can see the number of bytes used by resources in the selected assembly.

I am asking because I am working with Silverlight and my client executable (xap) is getting quite big. It's already possible to see the size of included DLL and resource files in the xap, but my main DLL is space hog, so I need go down to a code level to find out which modules are so fat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [CodeMetrics](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodeMetrics&referringTitle=Home) plugin for Reflector will help.